# Qustion form for answer below

Tags: questions

> There is a waiting time of approximately 60 minutes before check-in .

If I ask a question for this answer would the sentence below be correct?

> Approximately how many hour waitig time are there before check-in ?

I know there are different alternatives but I wonder if this form correct or not . Is this sentence grammatically correct ?

Comment: *About how long is [the] check-in wait / waiting time?*

Comment: Is my sentence correct ?

Comment: We don't do proofreading here - I just gave you a common alternative to your example question. Is there anything *specific* about your version that you're unsure of? If not, the question will get closed as Off Topic.

Comment: The part I couldn’t be sure is “ Approximately how many hour waitig time“. Is it correct to write this phrase written back to back ?

Comment: That's a rather long string of words combining several different aspects of vocabulary and syntax. I see that in your initial sentence describing the *actual* situation, you refer to *a waiting time **of** [some length of time].* Why did you discard the preposition ***of*** in your example *question?*

Comment: Then Should I say ; Waiting time of approximately how many hour are there before check-in ? But though what I wonder is “how many hour waitig time “ grammatically correct?

Comment: No. Suppose someone says they will give you a piece of string, and you want to know how long it is. You don't ask *Length of approximately how many inch is the string?* In terms of actual *grammar/syntax*, you MUST use plural ***inches / hours*** in any such context. But it would *still* be completely non-idiomatic (perhaps "ungrammatical", I'm not sure). What I was really trying to get at was whether you're having problems *because of that singular/plural issue*, or because of something else.

Comment: Note that you *might* ask *What length is the string?* or even *How many [inches, yards, whatever] long is the string?*, but *How long is the string?* is nearly always more natural. Also note that by actually *mentioning* the "unit of measurement" *(hours, minutes, inches, yards)*, you're implying that you expect an *answer* in those units. So if you're asking how many ***hours*** you might have to wait, at least they know you'll probably be pleasantly surprised if you're told it's "only" an hour or two.

Comment: Thank you so much